# html5 css3 realize background pattern

Tags: html, css, background

I have to realize this pattern for a background web site. Who can help me to realize the pattern? I don't know how it has to be developed.

I have realized the gradient with this css3 code:

```
background: rgb(152,152,152); /* Old browsers */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzk4OTg5OCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNmZmZmZmYiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxMDAlIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjZmZmZmZmIiBzdG9wLW9wYWNpdHk9IjEiLz4KICA8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PgogIDxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZC11Y2dnLWdlbmVyYXRlZCkiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(152,152,152,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#989898', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As commented, it is used as a fallback for some old browsers e.g. I.E.6

```
background: rgb(152,152,152); /* Old browsers */
```

Include an inline background image (using base64 encoding instead of a url)

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw...);
```

For the -xx-linear-gradient lines, we call it vendor-specific properties.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(152,152,152,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(152,152,152,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
```

They are not necessarily to be standard W3C rules. The purpose of the existence of vendor-specific props is to allow browser vendors to add their own CSS props for providing more features than what the standard suggested to developers.

The last line is used by I.E. that supports "filter" property.

So in short, the lines below the first line are just **doing the same job** but they are just designed for use by **different browsers**. It ensures that the element with the rules applied to look the same in all major browsers.

Comment: Sorry I have not understand...can you explain me with an example? thanks

Comment: um, I think your code is already a good example. Try it in different browsers and you will see the same result. That is what these lines for.